# How can I use an image from third-party package asset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this package in my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  country_code_picker: ^1.4.0
```

It is the repo: https://github.com/imtoori/CountryCodePicker

I would like to use the images from `flags/` directory

What do I need to do to use them from Image.asset() in flutter ?

Comment: You should copy them to your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the package:

```
Image.asset(
  'flags/ad.png',
  package: 'country_code_picker',
)
```